# Bootstrap Date Range Picker disable dates

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, daterangepicker

How do I block the availability of some dates in Date Range Picker?

For example:

```js
['22/07/2016', '26/07/2016', '29/07/2016']
```

Thank

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `isInvalidDate` function.

For example disable Sundays and Saturdays:

```
isInvalidDate: function(date) {
  return (date.day() == 0 || date.day() == 6);
}
```

Or disable specific date:

```
isInvalidDate: function(date) {
    if (date.format('YYYY-MM-DD') == '2016-08-01') {
        return true; 
    } else {
        return false; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I saw an example of this before, but something did not work.